# name 'session' is not defined for Tweepy

Tags: python, session, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use Tweepy to use Twitter streaming API and I'm following the documentation (http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html).

However, on the page, Im stuck at `http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html`. It gives me the error `name 'session' is not defined`. Since the tutorial doesn't say which library for session it's using, I cannot proceed. Could someone help?

My code:

```
session.set('request_token', auth.request_token)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: Thanks! It's "session.set('request_token', auth.request_token)"

Comment: Read the line above, "Here is a Pseudo example", it's not real code that you're copy-pasting into your project.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your full code, but I would suspect that you haven't defined session in your code. If you haven't, you'll get a NameError error like the following (the same one you have):

```
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

When you try to call a variable that hasn't been defined, you get a name error. Session needs to be defined somewhere. On the other hand, in Tweepy's Streaming API there doesn't appear to be any similar examples or instructions.

In the Streaming with Tweepy section of the API documentation, it says you need an API object [covered in the Authentication Tutorial](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html). At the bottom of said tutorial, you create an API object like so:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

In the Streaming with Tweepy section of the documentation, you use the API object to [create the stream](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=session#step-2-creating-a-stream):

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())
```

Of course, you need to follow the additional instructions on the page to [create the *Stream Listener* in step 1](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=session#step-1-creating-a-streamlistener) of *Streaming with Tweepy* and [to start the stream in step 3](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=session#step-3-starting-a-stream).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My code was "session.set('request_token', auth.request_token)". I just tried to follow the tutorial(http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html#auth-tutorial). I still don't know what the "session" can be. Would it be a certain library?

Comment: You need to specifically define it, and it doesn't look like you need it. Methods would be part of a certain library. Variables, like session, are not defined as part of a library.